# Dual nationality (two passports) entering Canada with one and USA with another?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, dual-nationality

I am citizen of two states (Serbia and Croatia). I would like travel to Canada with my Croatian passport (no Visa requirements for Croatian citizens) and enjoy country for few weeks with my bicycle and then to cross to USA with my Serbian passport which has valid US visa (10 years, multiple entries) and hike & cycle for couple weeks and return home. In Europe I have seen many times that people change passports, but is that practices normal overseas (Canada & US)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: He wants to travel to Canada using a Croatian passport, then from Canada to the USA using Serbian passport (because it already has a US visa). He wants to know if this will be allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: This should be fine.

Comment: @CMaster the proposed duplicate doesn't seem to address the question of using different passports in different countries when neither country being visited had issued either of the passports.

Answer (score 4):

*Caveat:  I am not an immigration lawyer*. Talk to one if you want to be sure

A word of warning upfront: US immigration is in general much more difficult to deal with than European, so I wouldn't assume European standards there. In Germany I can basically whip out both passports and ask them "blue or red?", which they would fine funny. In the US this would almost certainly gain a you an extended private interview with a senior immigration official.

In general it's good practice to enter and exit any country on the same passport. Sometimes governments cross check entry and exit record and using two different passports will bring up a red flag. I don't think it's illegal per se but it may lead to extended questioning when you leave or next time you enter.

Keep in mind that you do NOT have the right to enter the country (at least the US). Immigration officials can technically deny entry for pretty much any reason. They typically don't do this, but anything "unusual" increases the risk.

This being said: Depending on the border crossing, you could leave Canada with your Croatian passport and enter the US with the Serbian one.

Comment: Travelling between the U.S. and Canada there is only an entry check, not an exit check.  So you wouldn't have anyone to show your Croatian passport to when leaving Canada.  The U.S, and Canada share entry/exit info, too.  Both Canada and the U.S. will (potentially) know that you entered and left their respective territories using different passports--there is no way to avoid this without travelling to a third country.  Whether they will care, I'm not sure.

Comment: I've never explicitly asked about using my non-US passport when entering the US, but I've never hid it, either. My sister once did, and was faced with a false claim that having dual citizenship is "unconstitutional," but no extended interview or other delays.

Comment: If you have a US passport, you are legally required to use it when entering and exiting the US. See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality/dual-nationality.html

Comment: Of course. But there's no law against showing your other passport in addition to your US one, and doing so does not in my experience result in additional interviews with senior immigration officials.